# Datatables won't work with ajax POST type and GET type

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatables, routes

I used GET method first and I would get this error:
`414 (Request-URI Too Long)`
My ajax is like this:

```
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable( {
  stateSave: true,
  scrollX: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: {
    url: '/lista-evidencija-radnika-po-danu/tabela/'+ id + '/' + tip,
    type: 'GET',
    data: function ( d ) {
      d.zakljucano = $('#zakljucano').val();
    },
  },...
```

And my route:

```
Route::get('/lista-evidencija-radnika-po-danu/tabela/{id}/{tip}', 'EvidencijaRadnikaPoDanuController@tabela_evidencije');
```

But then i get error: **414 (Request-URI Too Long)**

If i switch to POST type adn switch my route to post i will get this error:**405 (Method Not Allowed)**

```
var table = $('#datatable').DataTable( {
  stateSave: true,
  scrollX: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: {
    url: '/lista-evidencija-radnika-po-danu/tabela/'+ id + '/' + tip,
    type: 'POST',
    data: function ( d ) {
      d.zakljucano = $('#zakljucano').val();
    },
  },...
```

And my POST route:

```
Route::post('/lista-evidencija-radnika-po-danu/tabela/{id}/{tip}', 'EvidencijaRadnikaPoDanuController@tabela_evidencije');
```

My controller

```
public function tabela_evidencije(Request $request, $id, $tip)
{
    $evidencija = EvidencijaRadnikaPoDanu::with('radnik', 'radnik.identifikacija')
        ->select('evidencija_radnika_po_danus.*', 'radniks.id_identifikacije')
        ->where('evidencija_radnika_po_danus.id_kompanije', Auth::user()->id_kompanije)
        ->where('evidencija_radnika_po_danus.id_radnih_dana', $id)
        ->where('evidencija_radnika_po_danus.tip', $tip);
    return datatables()->of($evidencija)
        ->editColumn('id_radnika', function ($data) {
            $puno_ime = $data->radnik->prezime.' '.$data->radnik->ime;
            return $puno_ime;
        })
        ->editColumn('id_ime', function ($data)  {
            return $data->radnik->ime;
        })
        //pomocu veze izmedju radnika i evidencija pronalazimo identifikacioni broj
        ->editColumn('id', function ($data)  {
            return $data->radnik->identifikacija->broj;
        })
        ->editColumn('id_radnika_modal', function ($data)  {
            return $data->id_radnika;
        })
        ->editColumn('id_modal', function ($data)  {
            return $data->id;
        })
    ->make(true);
}
```

**After inspecting it while using GET my URL is over 8,000 characters!**

Comment: Can you show us your controller please, and on you GET request, you add id and tip.

Try to add parameter to GET Route

Route::get('/lista-trajanja-odsustva/tabela/{id}/{tip}', 'TrajanjeOdsustvaController@tabela');

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-parameters

Comment: I coppied wrong route, sorry for that, I edited my question.

Comment: Is there any route prefixed with `lista-evidencija-radnika-po-danu`

Comment: No, but when i changed my ajax method to post and changed route to post, i had to run `php artisan optimize` in order for my changes to be accepted...

Answer (score 0):

I added in my `<head>` this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and added token in my ajax POST method

```
ajax: {
   url: '/lista-evidencija-radnika-po-danu/tabela/'+ id + '/' + tip,
   method: 'POST',
   'headers': {
       'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
   }...
```

And also changed my route to be post

```
Route::post('/lista-evidencija-radnika-po-danu/tabela/{id}/{tip}', 'EvidencijaRadnikaPoDanuController@tabela_evidencije');
```

And i had to run this command in my console

```
php artisan optimize
```

In order for my route to change to POST route...